# PHP Single Page Form Validation HTML - form not validating

Tags: php, html

PHP portion, where variables are initialized and set to empty. As well as the post methods and isset functions

The functions seem to be right, no errors when running the code. However, nothing is processed when the user submits everything. This is just a small portion of the code.

```
<?php


//define variables and set them to empty values    

$fname_error= $phone_error= $address1_error= $address2_error= $city_error= $state_error= $zipcode_error= "";

$fname= $phone= $address1= $address2= $city= $state= $zipcode= "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fname_error = "Missing";
    }
    else {
        $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        //now we check to see that the name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
            $fname_error = "Please use letters and white space only";
        }
    }

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

The Html portion:

```
                               <div class="userinput">
                                    <label for="fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php 
                                         echo $fname ?>">
                                    <span class="error">
                                        <?php echo $fname_error;?></span>
                                </div>
```

Comment: You are missing a } before the function test_input

Comment: When the user clicks the submit button at the bottom of the page, no input is saved and submitted or run through the functions (if statements, test_inputs, etc.) Nothing happens when you click submit. Whereas an error message should pop up when the user doesn't enter anything or invalid syntax

Comment: Try with this if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST')

Comment: That's probably because your PHP throws some erorrs which you don't see on screen. Activate error reporting, temporarily: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also, you should handle what happens when the `preg_match(..)` call is successfull.

Comment: Tried all of these suggestions, nothing happened. Its almost as if its not even registering the php section. Perhaps I forgot something or my form action is wrong.

Comment: Show us your <form> tag

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Comment: Pretty certain its not the form tag that is causing a problem. Perhaps its the location of the form tag? I have it before the <ol> html tag for the html section

Comment: Right after the first if, add this:  echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST),'</pre>'; and tell what it shows

Comment: José, that actually worked! it now validates the input for the name field. When empty, it displays "Missing!" Now the issue is telling it to validate good input and not display the missing message. - Could you please explain what this does? Or what I was doing wrong

Comment: Great, this is just for debugging the variables, we look into the $_POST array, now  we know that the problem is on the second if or the preg_match

Answer (score -1):

Close the conditional REQUEST_METHOD.
Your code should look like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
  <html>
   <head>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>  

    <?php
  //define variables and set them to empty values    

    $fname_error = $phone_error = $address1_error = $address2_error = $city_error = $state_error = $zipcode_error = "";

    $fname = $phone = $address1 = $address2 = $city = $state = $zipcode = "";
    //flag to validate and allow SQL insert if true
    $valid=true;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
            $fname_error = "Missing";
            $valid=false;
        } else {
            $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
            //now we check to see that the name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname)) {
                $valid=false;
                $fname_error = "Please use letters and white space only";
            }
        }
    }
    //filter your input for security reason
    function test_input($data) {
        $data1 = trim($data);
        $data2 = stripslashes($data1);
        $data3 = htmlspecialchars($data2);
        return $data3;
    }
    if($valid){
        //Add you insert SQL
    }
    ?>

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">  
        <label for="fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
        <span class="error">
            <?php echo $fname_error; ?></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>

    <?php
    //For testing porpuses:
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo $fname;
    ?>

</body>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

[Form validation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)